# syntax package causes compilation to break \cite command

Tags: syntax, cite-package

Adding the `syntax` package causes `\cite` commands to break with the following error:

```
Argument of \@citex has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
            \par 
l.5 ...high ceiling") \cite{resnick_lifelong_2017}
                                              .  enter code here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underscore character is made active by the `syntax` package and this confuses `\cite`.

You can disable the special treatment of the underscore by calling the package as

```
\usepackage[nounderscore]{syntax}
```

Comment: Better than the other answer I found - thanks

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to be due to the `syntax` package altering the way that underscore characters are treated.  The underscores in the reference name are the cause of the error.

I finally found the answer here:

https://www.ppsa.dk/article/backus-naur-form-latex

Adding a line to return the underscore behaviour back to normal fixed the problem:

```
\usepackage{syntax}
\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`\_=8 }
```